# Good book for learning about mathematical foundation of quantum physics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, mathematics

I've been trying to slog through Quantum Physics for Dummies, but can't even get past the first chapter.  There's a lot of talk of Bras, Kets, and Hilbert spaces, but I feel I'm missing the mathematical underpinnings that would make it understandable.

Can anyone recommend a good book to build up my mathematical foundation for quantum physics?  A textbook or study guide would be fine - I'd want a lot of examples and practice problems.  By the end of this venture, I'd like these concepts to be intuitive to me.

Comment: Seems that either or both of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/27056/1 and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/74000/ cover this. No? Also http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/139595/ and it's predecessor http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/193/.

Comment: Oy vey. I think this might be overkill to route someone to the mathematical physics type literature. It seems that he is just looking for more in depth mathematical exposition. For that I would suggest Dirac's Principle's of Quantum Mechanics. You don't need to study analysis in depth, but you will need to have a firm grounding in linear algebra. Hilbert space is really just an inner product vector space that converges everywhere. No need to study a book for that, but you need the linear algebra and calculus to understand the definition. Dirac doesn't even use this definition.